# Making an functional interface working with different object types

Tags: java

I have defined for my project an functional interface called `Function`. It has only one method, `call`, like this:

```
    public interface Function {
       public void call();
    }
```

And in my Field object, I have this:

```
    public class Field {
      private Square[][] matrix; //Square is dispensable.
      public Field(int rows, int cols) {
        matrix = new Square[rows][cols];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            this.matrix = new Square(i * Square.NORMAL_WIDTH, j * Square.NORMAL_HEIGHT);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

It works fine, and it resembles JavaScript, but yet I cannot pass the object of my attention to it. but consider that I want to develop this method:

```
    public void each(Function f){
      int rows = matrix.length;
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        int cols = matrix[i].length;
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
          f.call();
        }
      }
    }
```

It will attach certain piece of code (in this case, an Function implementation) to every element of the matrix. That way, I can access it's properties.
But every object of the matrix is an square. How can I access it? I could pass it to the function,

```
    //making an small alteration to the parameter.
    public interface Function {
       public void call(Square square);
    }

    public void each(Function f){
      int rows = matrix.length;
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        int cols = matrix[i].length;
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
          f.call(matrix[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
```

But still, I would be trapped to the `Square` type. I could make an use of generic types, maybe?

Comment: ...Yes, generics are how you solve that problem?

Comment: You might be better off not trying to turn Java into JavaScript.

Comment: Guess you're right. But, it is an useful interface, though. Maybe I get to use it in other parts of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to make it generic.

The simpliest case:

```
public interface Function<T> {
    public void call(T arg);
}

public void each(Function<Square> f) { ... }
```

The better practice is to declare `each()` as follows:

```
public void each(Function<? super Square> f) { ... }
```

so that you can apply not just `Function<Square>`, but also a `Function` of any of its supertype, such as

```
Function<Object> PRINT = new Function<Object>() {
    public void call(Object arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I wasn't aware of the `super` constraint in the declaration, only `extends`. Actually, are you sure that's not what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
private Square[][] matrix;
```

use

```
private Function[][] matrix;
```

and the code isn't tied to Square.  Of course, eventually it will get tied to a concrete class, but the code is less coupled.  (And I'm not sure if generics would help there or not since it's too early in the morning for me to think much harder :-)